# Embedding into a PPM p6 File with C, how to mask bits?

Tags: c, char, embed, unsigned, ppm

I'm trying to hide a message in a PPM file, (p6).  Awfully I just XOR'd my message with the red pixels.  This worked, but left a very noticeable change to the image.  I know a better way would be to use a bit mask, or just shift changing each LSB bit to a 1 or 0 if needed.  I'm having trouble doing this in C.

my data structs...

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char red,green,blue;
} PPMPixel;

typedef struct {
    int x, y;
    PPMPixel *data;
} PPMImage;
```

and my embed function...

```
unsigned char * embBits(PPMImage *img, int messageLen, unsigned char*msgOne, unsigned char *encMsg)
{
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char eMsg[messageLen]; 
    unsigned char bit;


    for(int j = 0; j < messageLen; j++)
    {
        //bit = msgOne[j];

        img->data[count].red = msgOne[j] ^ img->data[count].red;
    //  img->data[count].green = msgOne[j+1] ^ img->data[count].green; 
    //  img->data[count].blue = msgOne[j+2] ^ img->data[count].blue;
        eMsg[j] = img->data[count].red;
        count++;
    /*  
    // was thinking to look at each bit in RED / GREEN / BLUE
    // 1. start at 100000 and go down to 000001
    // 2. leave values that are the same / flip values that are different

        for(int k=7; 0 < k; k--)
        {               
            // bit & ( 1 << k);
        }
    */
    }

    return encMsg = eMsg;
}
```

I know I need to just flip the LSB if they don't match, but I'm having a rough time thinking of how to do this in C.  At first I was thinking about taking the first character stream - converting it to hex, converting that to binary, then taking the first bit and masking it into the red pixel, the 2nd bit with the green pixel and so forth.  I know an easier solution exists with just a simple shift and bitwise &, but I've yet to figure out.  Thanks for any help.

UPDATED:::: I haven't been able to test this yet, but I think this works by just looking at it.  I'm going to just have to update my output of the function to catch the new values of what I'm changing.

```
unsigned char * embBits(PPMImage *img, int messageLen, unsigned char*msgOne, unsigned char *encMsg)
{
    int count = 0;
    unsigned char eMsg[messageLen]; 
    unsigned char byte;
    unsigned char mask;
    unsigned char flipOne = 0x01;
    unsigned char flipZero = 0x00;

    for(int j = 0; j < messageLen; j++)
    {
        byte = msgOne[j];
        mask = 0x80;    

        for(int k=7; 0 < k; k--)
        {



byte = byte & mask;

            if(byte == 0)
            {
                //red
                if (mask == 0x80 || mask == 0x10 || mask == 0x02)
                {
                    //check LSB and FLIP 
                    img->data[count].red = img->data[count].red & flipZero;     
                }

                //green
                if (mask == 0x40 || mask == 0x08 || mask == 0x01)
                {
                    //check LSB and FLIP 
                    img->data[count].green = img->data[count].green & flipZero;     
                }

                //blue
                if (mask == 0x20 || mask == 0x03)
                {
                    //check

 LSB and FLIP 
                    img->data[count].blue = img->data[count].blue & flipZero;       
                }

            }   
            else
            {
                //flip bit
                //red
                if (mask == 0x80 || mask == 0x10 || mask == 0x02)
                {
                    //check LSB and FLIP 
                    img->data[count].red = img->data[count].red & flipOne;      
                }

                //green
                if (mask == 0x40 || mask == 0x08 || mask == 0x01)
                {


//check LSB and FLIP 
            img->data[count].green = img->data[count].green & flipOne;      
        }

        //blue
        if (mask == 0x20 || mask == 0x03)
        {
            //check LSB and FLIP 
            img->data[count].blue = img->data[count].blue & flipOne;        
        }



        }   

            mask = mask >> 1;
            count++;
        }

    }

    return encMsg = eMsg;
}
```

Comment: check this answer  -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/47990/1788956

Comment: thanks, very helpful link.  looks like my check is on track, just have to handle flipping the bits, then figure out a way to go backwards.